# How to plot multiple fields on a column or a bar chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, antd

Antv Charts - I have a dataset which includes a number of columns with numeric value. How can I plot multiple columns on the same axis ?

I tried making the y-axis an array of fields, but one of the fields gets hidden behind the other. How can I offset the field so that both fields can be displayed ?

I'm using AntV Charts and I need it to be column/bar chart. I see examples of Column with line, but that doesn't work for me. Also Antv charts have series and grouped examples, but my data is in 2 columns, not in a single column.